# React Native typescript styled-component does not accept extra prop

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying to use styled-components in a React Native project but when I use the component, typescript doesn't recognise the additional prop that I want to pass for styling.

Styled component

```
type StyledContainerProps = { color: string }

const StyledTextContainer = styled.View<StyledContainerProps>`
  background-color: ${({ color }) => color};
`;
```

Usage within return

```
<StyledTextContainer color={`${colour.darken(0.4).hex()}CC`}>
   <Text style={[styles.title, styles.whiteText]}>{text}</Text>
</StyledTextContainer>
```

---

The typescript error I get on the color prop shows

```
No overload matches this call.


Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
      Property 'color' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; color: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
      Property 'color' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps>'.
```

Even thoough the type is showing as

```
const StyledTextContainer: IStyledComponent<"native", Substitute<ViewProps, StyledContainerProps>> & typeof View
```

**Update**:
I have found an open issue stating a similar problem [here on github](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/4184)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `props` yet?

```js
const StyledTextContainer = styled.View<StyledContainerProps>`
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that give the exact same result